# XAMPP on Mac will render only HTML portion

Tags: php, html, macos, xampp

I'm new to this forum and I hope I'm not posting duplicates, I did search and found a not so similar post and with no final resolution so I figure I'll start this fresh post.
So I'm on an intel Mac (snow leopard) and I'm trying to learn some PHP. I installed XAMPP and turned on the Apache server and MySQL, then I created a new "Index.html" file in my user's "Sites" folder with the following code:

```
<html> 
<head></head> 
<body> 
 Agent: So who do you think you are, anyhow? 
 <br /> 
 <?php 
   // print output 
   echo 'Neo: I am Neo, but my people call me The One.'; 
 ?> 
 </body> 
</html>
```

When I access the page trough Chrome or Safari I get only the html portion:

Agent: So who do you think you are, anyhow?

What is it that I'm doing wrong, please help, I have being trying to figure this out for few days now. I set "display_errors = on" in the "php.ini" file according to another post I found but I don't get any error message, just the html output. I'm using TextEdit in plain text mode and the XAMPP examples work fine. Any ideas? Help please!

Answer (score 3):

modify the page extension - `index.php`

Answer (score 1):

Rename your file to `index.php`